# How to get correct utilization calculation using case statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a doubt as mentioned below. Could you please suggest on how to crack of this.
Need to correct utilization data.

Input:

```
WORK_DAY      SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES  ATTENDANCE_MINUTES  UTILIZATION      Expected Utilization
2022-06-09      259276.93             0                 540.1602708        0
2022-04-04      1683.88              480                 3.5080833        3.5080833
2022-05-03       0.00                480                 0.0123791          0
2022-05-27       0.18                480                 0.81547917       0.0000001
```

This is the requirement

```
SELECT 
   EMPLOYEE_ID , 
   DATE_FROM_PARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1) AS WORK_DAY_MONTH , 
   SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) AS SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES, 
   SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) AS ATTENDANCE_MINUTES , 
   CASE 
     WHEN SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0 
     WHEN SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0 
      ELSE IFF( COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY) > 0 ,
                ( ROUND( SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ), 2 ) / (480 * 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY)) ), 0 ) END AS "Utilization" 
 FROM 
      table 
 GROUP BY 
      EMPLOYEE_ID , 
      DATE_FROM_PARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1);


    
    Here for utilization part would like to modify a bit LIKE
    
    CASE WHEN SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0
        ELSE WHEN SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0
        ELSE IFF( COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY) > 0 ,( ROUND( SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ), 2 ) / (480 * COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY)) ), 0 ) END AS "Utilization"
```

Its throwing below error

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 7 unexpected
> 'WHEN'. syntax error line 4 at position 12 unexpected 'SUM'.

Comment: Try without the ELSE before next WHEN. (There's only one ELSE per CASE, or none.)

Comment: CASE WHEN SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0
     WHEN SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0-------------SQL compilation error: [table.WORK_DAY] is not a valid group by expression

Comment: no.. SQL compilation error: [table.WORK_DAY] is not a valid group by expression

Comment: Since you don't show us the complete query, we can't help.

Comment: SELECT 
EMPLOYEE_ID ,
DATE_FROM_PARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1) AS WORK_DAY_MONTH ,
SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) AS SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES,
SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) AS ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ,
CASE WHEN SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0
 WHEN SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN Utilization= 0
  ELSE IFF( COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY) > 0 ,( ROUND( SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ), 2 ) / (480 * COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY)) ), 0 ) END AS "Utilization"  
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
EMPLOYEE_ID ,
DATE_FROM_PARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1);

Comment: SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 45 'table.UTILIZATION' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247586/discussion-between-user3840800-and-jarlh).

Comment: Add it to the GROUP BY and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works well in sql-server:

```
SELECT 
   EMPLOYEE_ID , 
   DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1) AS WORK_DAY_MONTH , 
   CASE 
     WHEN SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES) = 0 THEN  0   
     WHEN SUM( SERVICE_NOW_MINUTES ) = 0 THEN  0 
      ELSE IIF( COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY) > 0 ,
                ( ROUND( SUM( ATTENDANCE_MINUTES ), 2 ) / (480 * 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT WORK_DAY)) ), 0 ) END
 FROM 
      table1 
 GROUP BY 
      EMPLOYEE_ID ,  
      DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(WORK_DAY), MONTH(WORK_DAY), 1);
```